# Republic of Ireland zip codes

Tags: data, geocoding, ireland

Is anyone aware of an open source exhaustive list of geocoded (WGS84 lat long) zip codes for the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: You might try asking on the [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com) Stackexchange. I just looked and didn't see any existing questions that matched.

Comment: To my knowledge, ZIP codes are unique to the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Ireland from below website :  http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/  Ireland prefix is **IE**

Download:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/IE.zip

Comment: Most welcome @csetzkorn

Answer (score 2):

Republic of Ireland unfortunately uses their own solution for postal codes called Eircode, which has closed source and working on it directly comes with some license fees, that aren't even publicly listed on their website.

I have done some research and found small database that's good enough for most use cases database of postcodes (grouped by routing keys) that also comes with names and WSG84 geographical coordinates.

The database can be found below under "IE.zip" filename:
https://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

Answer (score -3):

A search `postal codes lat long` turned up this: https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Comment: Republic of Ireland is not part of the UK.

Comment: Exactly... Have Uk ones including northern Ireland.